# Is there a loop I can use to tidy up this code?

Tags: r, loops

```
replace.value(zdata, c(1), DL[1], 0)  
replace.value(zdata, c(2), DL[2], 0)  
replace.value(zdata, c(3), DL[3], 0)  
replace.value(zdata, c(4), DL[4], 0)  
replace.value(zdata, c(5), DL[5], 0)  
replace.value(zdata, c(6), DL[6], 0)  
replace.value(zdata, c(7), DL[7], 0)  
replace.value(zdata, c(8), DL[8], 0)
```

I need to change a specific value (which are given in the DL vector) with 0 for each column of the data frame. For example the first value of the DL vector is 0.5 so the first line of the code above changes every 0.5 in the first column of the data frame to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Let's make some improvements. First of all, `c()` stands for *concatenate*, which means to "stick things together". If you only have one thing, you don't need `c()`. `5` is the same as `c(5)`, `"hello"` is the same as `c("hello")`, etc.

A `for`loop lets you loop over specific values. The values you change in each line of code go from 1 to 8, so we'll loop over that:

```
for (val in 1:8) {
  replace.value(zdata, val, DL[val], 0)
}
```

I don't know the `replace.value` function (and you don't mention what package it's in), but it seem strange that you aren't assigning the results. In base R, you'd do something like this:

```
zdata[1][zdata[1] == DL[1]] <- 0
zdata[2][zdata[2] == DL[2]] <- 0
...
```

Using `<-` to assign the result so it is saved. That would turn into this for loop:

```
for (val in 1:8) {
  zdata[val][zdata[val] == DL[val]] <- 0
}
```

Comment: The `replace.value` function is in the package `anchors` and it seemed to be auto-changing the input. Originally I had `replace.value(zdata, c(1:45), DL[1:45], 0)` but I realised that it was changing every occurrence of every value in DL in the whole data frame. Your solution works a treat! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `tidyverse` more explicitly, you can use something like `walk`

```
library(tidyverse)
walk(1:8, ~replace.value(zdata, .x, DL[.x], 0))
```